# OrmSqlite automap Results

Tags: android

I am using OrmSqlite database, want to auto map the results in           GenericRawResults rawResults

```
    String querString = "select * from ZADDRISKDETAILS where ZRISK_DEFINED_STATUS='" + status + "' AND ZPROJECTID ='" + projectID + "' AND ZRESPECTIVE_USERID ='" + userID + "' AND ZRISKDATETIME like '" + selectedYear + "%' ";
    GenericRawResults<String[]> rawResults = mDBHelper.getRecommendationPinDetailsDao().queryRaw(querString);
    List<String[]> results = rawResults.getResults();

   for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            ListModel model = new ListModel();
            model.setDueDate(results.get(i)[2]);
            model.setRiskCategory(results.get(i)[8]);
            model.setRiskObservation(results.get(i)[14]);
            model.setStatus(results.get(i)[11]);
            model.setPriority(results.get(i)[19]);
            model.setRiskRecommendation(results.get(i)[21]);
            model.setIssuedDate(results.get(i)[10]);
          }
```

I want to map those results directly to map model class obj. (Eg. ListModel.class) without giving the index. I think RawRowMapper does this, but no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use Dio to map model class,

```
private Dao<News, Integer> newsDao = null;

public Dao<News, Integer> getNewsDao() {
    if (null == this.newsDao) {
        try {
            this.newsDao = getDao(News.class);
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return this.newsDao;
}

public List<News> getAllNews() {
    List<News> news = null;
    try {
        news = getHelper().getNewsDao().queryForAll();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return news;
}
```

It may help you..

Comment: You are querying for all in table and map the entire result to object, I know it works but i want to be work with custom query as mentioned in above code from rawResults.